# Slanted version of the symbols \gtreqqless and \lesseqqgtr

Tags: pdftex, symbols, amsmath, math-operators, amssymb

I was looking the list of the symbols but I think that this that I have created with Windows Paint not exist?

[image]

It is the slanted version of the symbols `\gtreqqless` and `\lesseqqgtr` of `amssymb`.

> Is it true or did I look wrong?

Comment: The packages `MnSymbol` and `fdsymbol` provide them, but you can easily make them yourself.

Comment: @campa It is true :-( I have not seen it :-(: `\lesseqslantgtr`. But it is very small instead of the size of the classical symbols of `amssymb`: it is different style. I would a day to use it with `amssymb` or `amssfont`, but I not know the slot of `\lesseqslantgtr`. But I am I without eyesight. :-(

Comment: The first one is simply `\leqslant`. How is the second one slanted?

Comment: @Bernard The symbol is one. Consider it all together. Cropping with Paint is bad :-(. Sorry: I still have to answer the math question that I will have to edit but had voted on this afternoon.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Oh! I see. I would do that with the `\stackinset` command from ` `stackengine`.

Comment: @Bernard Excuse me for the bad image :-(. I ask my apologies for Steven because I forgot often his package. After I have negated with the English language without the translator (not often).

Comment: @Sebastiano: No worries…The advantage of \stackinset is that it's very easy to fine-tune the spacing (both horizontal and vertical).

Comment: Bernard it is impressive. I have written that "*I still have to answer the math question that I will have to edit but had voted on this afternoon*"...and now I have received a downvote :-)...ahahahah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages `MnSymbol` and `fdsymbol` provide them as `\lesseqgtrslant` and `\gtreqlessslant`. If you don't like them you can build them up from CM glyphs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lesseqgtrslant}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@gtr@less@eq{\leqslant>}}}
\newcommand*{\gtreqlessslant}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@gtr@less@eq{\geqslant<}}}
\newcommand*{\@gtr@less@eq}[2]{%
   \vcenter{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \m@th
      \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\@secondoftwo#2$}%
      \hbox{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$}%
      \kern-.2\ht0  % <--- had to guess this...
      \box0
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
$a \lesseqgtrslant a \gtreqlessslant a$\\[1ex]
$\scriptstyle a \lesseqgtrslant a \gtreqlessslant a$\\[1ex]
$\scriptscriptstyle a \lesseqgtrslant a \gtreqlessslant a$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** In order to reduce the vertical size you can squeeze the box However, squeezing it too much will result in thinner lines. Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` and replace the above definition of `\@gtr@less@eq` by

```
\newcommand*{\@gtr@less@eq}[2]{%
   \offinterlineskip
   \m@th
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\@secondoftwo#2$}%
   \hbox{$#1\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1}[.85]{\vbox{\hbox{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$}\kern-.2\ht0\box0}}}}$}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very elegant. But do you think it's too big when written in inline mode?

Comment: @Sebastiano Well, yes, I find them too big, but so are `\gtreqqless` and `\lesseqqgtr`. You can squeeze them vertically if you want, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: From by changing \kern-.2?

Comment: @Sebastiano No, by putting everything in something like `\scalebox{1}[.9]`. I'll edit.

Comment: Excuse me very much for the delay to give you the green check mark.

Comment: @Sebastiano No worries.